# How to run a LINQ query on a collection of objects and a collection inside of each object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of objects where each object also has a collection. Like so:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<string, double>> Sales { get; set; }
}
```

I want to run a LINQ query to check if a Product entity exists and, if it does exist, check it's Sales collection to see if a specific string value (from the Tuple) also exists. If it does, I want to return the corresponding double (also from the Tuple).

I know I can do this in a few lines of code, like so:

```
saleAmount = String.Empty;                      
product = Model.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == product.Id);
if(product != null)
{
    productSale = product.Sales.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Item1 == sale.Id);
    if(productSale != null)
    {
        saleAmount = productSale.Item2.ToString();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in one line?

Comment: You'll be exposed to `NullReferenceExceptions` and I doubt your code would be any clearer.

Comment: You realize, I hope, that `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if more than one item in the list has that produce id. Are you sure you don't want `FirstOrDefault` here?

Comment: @JimMischel Given that he's dealing with primary keys, they shouldn't be duplicated.  If they somehow were, it would be a bug in the data and *should* throw.

Comment: @Servy if they are primary keys, then (nickpicking here) `FirstOrDefault` is performance wise faster (because it's doesn't need to check to see if there are duplicates to throw the exception).

Comment: @Servy: I didn't see anything that said he was working with a primary key. But if that's the case, then of course.

Comment: @ErikPhilips This looks like it's IQueryable code, not work done in memory, so it's not like it's doing linear searches through in memory collections.

Comment: @JimMischel I am working with primary keys, so SingleOrDefault is the correct choice in this particular case.

Comment: @ShaiCohen I updated my answer to provide two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to not actually materialize your query through the use of `SingleOrDefault` until you're actually done defining the entirety of it.  Use `Where` instead and then use `SingleOrDefault` at the very end.

```
var query = (from product in Model.Products
                where product.Id == someProductId
                let sale = product.Sales.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Item1 == sale.Id)
                where sale != null
                select new
                {
                    product,
                    saleAmount = sale.Item2,
                })
            .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: That's a really interesting approach. Is this possible using lambda expressions?

Comment: @ShaiCohen This *is* using lambda expressions.

Comment: @ShaiCohen A `lambda` expression is the conditional expression which extrapolates a specific check grammar via the "goes to" `=>` syntax. The `lambda` you are thinking is the `linq` expression which can be in a *query* syntax as Servy has done (technically he has a mixture) or as the *method* syntax which I used in my example. Both of ours use `lambda`s to express a check operation such as the `i => i.Item1 == sale.Id`. See [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) for more info.

Comment: @OmegaMan: Thank you for the clarification. Just when you think you know something .... :)

Comment: @ShaiCohen We have all been there. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it in one line.

I believe you can distill your code to less lines by combining the check into the second sales array such as

```
var products = Model.Products.Where(p => p.Id == product.Id
                                              &&
                                         p.Sales.Any(i => i.Item1 == sale.Id) );

var saleAmount = (products != null && products.Any()) 
                                   ? products.First().Sales.First().Item2.ToString()
                                   : string.Empty;
```

### Using a Default Value

This solution uses the help from a default *faux* pre-created `Product` to be used when one is not found. Using it in the extension method [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx), that method determines if a empty projection has been returned and in that case it will instead return the faux instance. After that we can safely extract a the value which would be `string.empty` and assign it to the final string `productSale`.

Below I use a hardcoded `1.5` as the sale price for easier reading of the example.

```
// Our default will set saleAmount to string.Empty if nothing is found in Products.
var defProduct = new Product() 
                      { Id    = -1, 
                        Sales = new List<Tuple<string, double>>()
                                  { new Tuple<string,double>(string.Empty, 0.0) }};

var productSale =

Products.Where(p => p.Id == product.Id && p.Sales.Any (s => s.Item2 == 1.5 ) )
        .DefaultIfEmpty( defProduct )
        .First ()
        .Sales.First()
        .Item1;
```

`productSale` is string.Empty if no value found or has the actual value to use.

---

Whole test project in LinqPad which simulates a fail by using 1.5. Use 1.6 to show success.

```
void Main()
{

    var targetSalePrice = 1.5;
    var targetProductId = 2;

    var Products = new List<Product>() { new Product()
                                           { Id = 2,
                                             Sales = new List<Tuple<string, double>>()
                                            { new Tuple<string,double>("actual", 1.6) } }
                                        };


// Our default will set saleAmount to string.Empty if nothing is found in Products.
var defProduct = new Product() { Id = -1, Sales = new List<Tuple<string, double>>()
                                  { new Tuple<string,double>("faux string.Empty", 0.0) }};

var productSale =

Products.Where(p => p.Id == targetProductId 
                   && p.Sales.Any (s => s.Item2 == targetSalePrice ) )
        .DefaultIfEmpty( defProduct )
        .First ()
        .Sales.First ()
        .Item1;

    productSale.Dump(); // outputs the string "faux string.Empty" from the faux default.

}

// Define other methods and classes here


public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<string, double>> Sales { get; set; }
}
```